# How to covert .ipynb to slides using nbconvert?

Tags: terminal, ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-api-python-client

I created ipython notebook and I am be able to convert it to HTML and PDF. 
But when I tried to convert to it slides it turned out just like HTML on one file. Here is the code I use from a terminal prompt:

```
$ ipython nbconvert --slides Testing.ipynb --post serve
```

I want to create slides and I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7829). What version of IPython are you on? If less than 3, try upgrading.

Comment: Ipython is up to date and mine is version 3.0.0 @  Thomas K.

Comment: Any errors in the terminal or the JS console when you open it up in the browser?

Comment: When you wrote "it turned out just like HTML on one file" did you mean that the converted html file was displayed as a single page? another Q, in which browser is the converted file loaded?

Comment: Can someone send me a link on how to convert an IPython notebook file to PDF? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the following extra option to your code might solve the problem.

```
--reveal-prefix "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/2.5.0"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can also change theme and transition for eye-candy by adding extra code at the end of URL displayed on your web browser.

Assuming the URL is 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Testing.slides.html#/`, 
changing the url to
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/Testing.slides.html?theme=sky?transition=convex` will add some visual effect to your presentation.

For the version 2.6.2 or 2.5.0 of reveal.js, the following themes and transitions seem to be available: theme - `simple (default), sky, beige, solarized, serif, night, moon`
transition - `none, fade, slide, convex, concave, zoom`. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Thank you very much and definitely added a nice visualization to slideshows.@tanemaki

Answer (score 1):

The current version of reveal.js is not supported by Jupyter notebook so you can use the following command for now:

```
$ ipython nbconvert --slides Testing.ipynb --post serve --reveal-prefix "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/2.5.0"
```